# Aggregate functions in Magento ORM

Tags: magento

How to use aggregate functions like sum(), count() in Magento ORM.

Consider there is a table "test" with following values

```
-------------------------------------
productid           |          qty
-------------------------------------
1                   |            2
-------------------------------------
2                   |            3
-------------------------------------
3                   |            5
-------------------------------------
```

and if i mapped this table in my module,so that i can get collection data like

```
$_collection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/customcart')->getCollection();
```

how do i get result equivalent to below query with COLLECTION?

```
select sum(qty) from test;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your `mymodule/customcart` collection is EAV based you can use [`addExpressionAttributeToSelect`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Eav/Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract.html#addExpressionAttributeToSelect)

```
$_collection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/customcart')->getCollection();
$_collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('qty', 'SUM({{item_qty}})', 'item_qty')
    ->groupByAttribute('productid');
```

Otherwise you will have to work with the SQL more directly:

```
$_collection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/customcart')->getCollection();
$_collection->getSelect()
    ->columns('SUM(item_qty) AS qty')
    ->group('productid');
```

Be careful when using aggregated collections with grids or pagers. They rely on [`getSelectCountSql`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Data/Varien_Data_Collection_Db.html#getSelectCountSql) which doesn't handle grouped queries well, you might have to provide your own `getSelectCountSql` function which returns an accurate count.

Comment: @clockworkgeek how can i try this query in magento collection :
select sum(qty + productid - any_other_columns) from test;

Comment: @VijayS if you cannot work it out from the above because your situation is different then please start a new question, perhaps referencing this one and explaining how it differs.